# SSRS Convert Seconds to MM:SS Without Truncating

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I am formatting average handle time as mm:ss but it seems to be truncating.  I viewed the articles that came up under questions that may have your answer, none of them are working for my situation.
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, designing SSRS reports.
The calculation is currently using the format function.

The value displayed is 05:30.  The actual value should be 05:31.

Numbers in the calculation:
2,354,739 EmailHandleTimeTotal
7,119 EmailsTotal

Value in seconds = 330.7682

Code:

=Format(DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!ID_EmailHandleTimeTotal_.Value) / Sum(Fields!ID_EmailsTotal_.Value, 0), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss")

Looking for help displaying the result as 05:31 please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just round the seconds, for example like this:

```
=Format(CDate("00:00:00").AddSeconds(Round(Sum(Fields!ID_EmailHandleTimeTotal_.Value) / Sum(Fields!ID_EmailsTotal_.Value))), "mm:ss")
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!